# How to split up function from arguments in bash?

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I am writing a bash script named safeDel.sh with base functionalities including:

- file [file1, file2, file3...]
- -l
- -t
- -d
- -m
- -k
- -r arg

For the single letter arguments I am using the built in function getops which works fine. The issue I'm having now is with the 'file' argument. The 'file' argument should take a list of files to be moved to a directory like this:

```
$ ./safeDel.sh file file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt
```

The following is a snippet of the start of my program :

```
#! /bin/bash

files=("$@")
arg="$1"
echo "arguments: $arg $files"
```

The echo statement shows the following:

```
$ arguments : file file
```

How can I split up the file argument from the files that have to be moved to the directory?

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) finds one of the problems with the code snippet (incorrect use of an array variable).

Comment: With an array, `echo "$files"` is just like `echo "${files[0]}"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the options processed by `getopts` have been shifted off the command line arguments list, and that a check has been done to ensure that at least two arguments remain, this code should do what is needed:

```
arg=$1
files=( "${@:2}" )

echo "arguments: $arg ${files[*]}"
```

`files=( "${@:2}" )` puts all the command line arguments after the first into an array called `files`.  See [Handling positional parameters [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/posparams) for more information.

`${files[*]}` expands to the list of files in the `files` array inside the argument to `echo`.  To safely expand the list in `files` for looping, or to pass to a command, use `"${files[@]}"`.  See [Arrays [Bash Hackers Wiki]](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/arrays).

Comment: Or, `arg=$1; shift; files=("$@")`

Answer (score 1):

This is a way you can achieve your needs:

```
#!/bin/bash

declare -a files="$@"
for fileToManage in ${files}; do
  echo "Managing ... $fileToManage"
done
```

But it works only if there is no space in your file names, in which case you need to do some additional work.

Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Parentheses **are** necessary of you want to safely loop over the files in `files` or pass them as arguments to other commands.  See [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/264812), particularly the "How do I process a list of file names?" section in the (excellent) accepted answer.

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies inappropriate use of `"$@"` in the code.

Comment: And no `space` between the *pound-bang* and the interpreter.

Comment: Note that when `files` names an array, `${files}` is equivalent to `${files[0]}` which is probably not what's wanted.  Use `"${files[@]}"` to iterate over the elements of the array sanely.  The `declare -a files="$@"` notation maps all the arguments in `"$@"` into a single argument.  You really need `declare -a files=("$@")` to get multiple elements in the array.  See Bash manual on [`declare`](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-declare) and [arrays](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Arrays) — and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

```
function getting_arguments {
    # using windows powershell
    echo @($args).GetType()
    echo @($args).length
    echo "@($args)[0]"
    echo @($args)[0]
    echo "@($args)[1..(@($args).length)]"
    echo @($args)[1..(@($args).length)]

    echo "debug: $(@($args)[0])" @($args)[1..(@($args).length)]
}
```

OUTPUT

```
PS C:\monkey> getting_arguments 1 2 3 4 5 6

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
6
@(1 2 3 4 5 6)[0]
1
@(1 2 3 4 5 6)[1..(@(1 2 3 4 5 6).length)]
2       
3       
4       
5       
6       
debug: 1
2       
3       
4       
5       
6
```